# php select entire table and set variables from multiple rows by id

Tags: php, mysql, variables, select

I am very new to PHP so if this answer is out there already I apologize.  I have a table that looks like this:

```
mcID | mcName
-------------
M1   | M1name
M2   | M2name
M3   | M3name
M4   | M4name
```

I know how to write four separate sql select statements to get these into variables but that seems like overkill.  I am wondering if there is a way to run a single select statement to set all four variables.  My current code to set one variable is below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblmaincircles WHERE mcID='M1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $M1 = $row["mcName"];
    }
}
else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  I have a feeling I am missing something really basic.  Thanks!

Comment: And what if `SELECT * FROM tblmaincircles`?

Comment: The `where` isn't required, if you don't want to limit the results then don't use a `where`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html; `The WHERE clause, if given, indicates the condition or conditions that rows must satisfy to be selected. where_condition is an expression that evaluates to true for each row to be selected. The statement selects all rows if there is no WHERE clause.`

Comment: I knew the WHERE clause will exclude all others.  I was simply showing my current code.  I knew I needed to remove this clause in order to make it work but I prefer to share a working piece of code instead of something that is broken from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is a way to run a single select statement to set all four variables.

Yes, there's a way. You can use a single query and store the values in the corresponding variables using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblmaincircles";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $$row['mcID'] = $row["mcName"];  // Variable variables
    }

    // display variables
    echo $M1;

    // Like this you can display or use any variable like $M2, $M3 and $M4

}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Great answer. TRiNE just beat you to it.  Thanks!

Comment: @CraigHowell See the timestamp of my answer and TRiNE's answer. Anyway, glad to know that the issue is resolved.

Comment: You are correct.  I was just going in flow of the feed.  I changed the answer to yours.  Thanks again!

Comment: @CraigHowell No matter who gives the answer first. If the question is resolved, that's it. No need to compete. No need to compare. :)

Comment: Thanks TRiNE, I am new to this forum so thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

I used **array** -> [Array Manual](http://php.net/manual/it/language.types.array.php)

**var_dump** function -> [Var_dump](http://php.net/manual/it/function.var-dump.php)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblmaincircles";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$arrayMc = [];
if($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       $arrayMc[] = $row["mcName"];
    }

   var_dump($arrayM);
}
else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly what you expect and doesn't use arrays. check for M1,M2.. variables

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblmaincircles";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $$row["mcID"]= $row["mcName"];
    }
}
else {
   echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: @chris85 if you go through the question and compare rdn87 answer and my one, you will see the difference. Craig Howell needs to store the result in variables not in an array. that is what i mentioned and not meant whole code segment is independent of using arrays.

Comment: It is set to one variable because `WHERE mcID='M1'`. So the result set is one row.

Comment: @chris85 yes. so I removed where clause in my answer. but that is not the only thing he expect. those results should be stored in separate 4 variables called M1, M2.. so what's wrong with my answer please?

Comment: Nothing is wrong aside from the text `doesn't use arrays`, there are arrays, just not for the assignment. I dont like variable variables in my code because then there are magic variables appearing later in the code. I'd use an array with an index of the columns id for it's value; or multi dimensional if many results..

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for!  Thanks TRiNE!